# Numerical integration, number sort,$\int \sin \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)dx$

Tags: integration, sorting

[image: This is the whole topic]

[image: image 2]

The blue line is the value of the lookup (the method is similar to the punctuation in Figure 2).
 Is there a smarter way?

Comment: Do you just want a smart way to sort the original integrals?

Comment: not clear what you are doing, or what you are asking

Comment: Yes, just want to sort the original integrals. Sorry for the late reply, my time here is early morning, so I need to adjust the status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\in[0,\,\pi/4]$, $0\le\sin x\le x\le\tan x\le 1$, so $0\le\sin(\sin x)\le\sin x\le\sin(\tan x)\le\sin 1$, whence $J<I<K$.

Comment: This method is too clever, I am very admired, and I am very grateful. This has hit my confidence to follow the practice. Maybe I am too lacking in mathematics. This topic can be done in such a smart way. Maybe this is the intention of the person who made the question. I have a lot of similar topics that require sorting integrals, I hope you can teach me smarter in the future.

Comment: @exgirlfriend You just need to get used to reasoning that, even if you don't know an obvious way to compute or estimate an integral, you can bound it by bounding the integrand. That's all we've really done here.

Comment: Ok, I will train my reaction, make my reaction more skillful and clever, try to used to reasoning that, can bound it by bounding the integrand. I will keep this in mind.